# TensorFlow: Predicting with already trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have trained a seq2seq model and saved it with `tf.Saver()`.
Now, the model I've been playing with has those placeholders:

```
encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs')
encoder_inputs_length = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs_length')
decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')
```

Let's focus on `decoder_targets`. This placeholder is the wanted result if I recall correctly. This is a problem. If I want to predict a translation (this means that I have no 'wanted result'), what could I do?

This is what I have currently

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

saver = tf.train.Saver()

encoder_inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs')
encoder_inputs_length = tf.placeholder(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='encoder_inputs_length')
decoder_targets = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, None), dtype=tf.int32, name='decoder_targets')

encoder_inputs_ = 0
encoder_inputs_length_
lol = 0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore model
    saver.restore(sess, "./rsc/model.ckpt")
    # Init
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    # Test
    sess.run(lol, feed_dict={encoder_inputs: encoder_inputs_, encoder_inputs_length: encoder_inputs_length_, ?????})
```

Do I need to write the whole model in this file too? (sorry for the code, I was testing a few things)

Comment: You dont pass `decoder_targets` if `lol` is not dependent on it, just pass the other two.